# How can I test AutoComplete component with WicketTester

Tags: java, wicket-tester

I'm wondering if anyone of you could know how to test auto-complete textfield using wickettester, I have tried

```
formTester.setValue("path","");
wicketTester.executeAjaxEvent("path","onchange");
```

I've tried also:

```
Component component = wicketTester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("path");
component.setDefaultModelObject(ObjectNeeded);
```

But none of these methods worked for me...
Any Help will appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this with real code, but something resembling this might work:

```
formTester.setValue("path","");

AbstractAutoCompleteBehavior behavior = (AbstractAutoCompleteBehavior)
WicketTesterHelper.findBehavior(wicketTester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("path"),
AbstractAutoCompleteBehavior.class);
wicketTester.executeBehavior(behavior);
```

The `findBehavior` call actually likely needs to be a longer path, as it's not done by `formTester`.

Comment: Hi @don roby, I'm using a very old version of wicket(1.4) and most of the method like findBehavior are not implemented yet with this version. I have looked the source code of this method and I have found that inside they are using other methods that also haven't been implemented yet..., so I don't think i'm going to reimplement all of these methods, also I can't change to a recent version of wickettester because the project was developed with the version 1.4...

Comment: When I was doing 1.4, I think I had to write my own findBehavior to do anything resembling this.  So with a bit more work, you might be able to accomplish it even in 1.4.